# How to add a theme to Abstract Class that extends ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

How do I set a theme on a Abstract Activity?

My Abstract Base class is extending ActionBarActivity now but the compiler is complaining about

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

From my understanding a Abstract Base Class cannot be instantiated, therefore I can't put it in AndroidManifest and set a theme.

I tried setting the theme in java to no avail.

EDIT:
Here's a partials from the implementation:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".Startup.Startup"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" 
        ....
        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
```

Comment: what about its concrete implementations?

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` need support library V7, what's your activity/app theme ? show your style

Comment: But what's about the Activity launched when the app starts ?

Comment: everything seems legit ....styles and manifest...